# Index and Match with mulitple sheets and parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

At work we have a large collection of sheet that I'm trying to add a couple columns to.

Some of the Index functions were already in the sheets so I am trying to base my new index function off of it because I have never used these types of functions in Excel. The old function is as follows.

```
=INDEX('Order Detail'!$D:$D,MATCH($A9,'Order Detail'!$B:$B,0))
```

Order detail is the name of the sheet that is holding the date for the output.
A9 is the part number in the current sheet.
And the part numbers are listed in column B or the order detail sheet.

What I know want to do is match the part numbers for the two sheets and match the dept number. The dept number is located in column L of the order detail sheet and I want that to match 1000-1. Not 1000 minus 1 actual 1000-1.

IF both of those match I want to spit out the data from column O in the order detail sheet and output that in column U starting at U9 and down in the current sheet.

This is what I have so far for this but it does not work.

```
=INDEX('Job Routing'!$O:$O,MATCH($A9,'Job Routing'!$B:$B,0),MATCH('Job Routing'!$L:$L,"1000-1"),0)
```

I only want it to output the O column if the Part Number AND Dept Number are the same as the part number in A9 and the dept number the same as 1000-1.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Usually in this type of situation I would make a concatenation of the values of the three different columns and then base the index-match function off of that. Would this work in your situation?

Comment: Why not just do like `=If([first index/match]=[second index/match],[return value],"")` that way, both index/match have to be equal, and if so, you can put whatever in the [return value] place.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, this is my first time ever using matches in excel so I'm completely lost

Comment: try `=INDEX('Job Routing'!$O:$O,MATCH($A9,IF('Job Routing'!$L:$L="1000-1",'Job Routing'!$B:$B),0))`

Comment: This lets me enter the formula in without throwing an error, but it is still outputting the same output as the first formula. I'm not sure how it is doing that though because Order detail and Job Routing are two completely different sheets. I think this formula will work once I figure out the output situation though. Thanks!

Comment: This is an array formula and must use ctrl-shift-enter to confirm.  Make sure you are in edit mode and then hit ctrl-shift-return.

Comment: it is still giving me the same output. The output from the original equation was a date and the output from this equation should be a number, not sure if that changes the formula at all or not. the new output will be a number located in the column O for the second sheet

Comment: It should output what is in Column O.  Maybe you need to format the cells in which you put the formula to "General" instead of a date.

Comment: And just like that I feel like an idiot. I copied the formula from a cell that was formatted as a date and I didn't change it back until you said something. Thank you so much!